# Redis select error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: laravel, redis

Why am I getting an error? What am I doing wrong?

my code

```php
//error
Redis::getset('access-token','<value>','EX',10);
```

error

```yaml
`SELECT` failed: ERR value is not an integer or out of range
```

please help me

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @ac.0101010111  

Predis\Connection\ConnectionException
`SELECT` failed: ERR value is not an integer or out of range [tcp://redis:6379]

Comment: `Redis::getset('access-token','<value>','EX',10);` Are these the real values or you replaced them with an examples?

Comment: Have you added redis configuration properly in environment file? Also try to connect redis server using Redis desktop and verify whether are you able to connect or not?